# why the first index of the column of a matrix is negative?

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, char, coordinates

why in this simple part of code to modify the point in the lower left of the bidimensional array have I to put in the coordinate `m[37][-40]`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 40

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char m[MAX][MAX];

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        for(j=0; j<MAX; j++)
            m[i][j]=' ';
    }

    m[37][-40]='X';

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        for(j=0; j<MAX; j++)
            printf("%c", m[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Souldn't it be `m[37][0]`? Becouse the row is 37 and the column is 0...

Comment: but if i put m[37][0] like it should be the 'X' isn't on the extreme left, but some spaces later

Comment: Are you sure it isn't your terminal wrapping the line? Try putting other (visible) characters in the empty cells.

Comment: @Jashaszun  Why is it undefined behavior?  Surely with pointer arithmetic, `m[37][-40]` is still within `char m[MAX][MAX]`.

Comment: @chux Oh wow, of course that's true. Umm, I retract my previous UB comment. However, it's still terrible to do this. :)

Comment: @Jashaszun Would not say this is terrible.  Negative indexes are often used.  Yes, they are prone to mis-use. OP is simply pushing the boundaries.

Comment: @OP With `char m[40][40]; m[37][-40]='X';` it is the same as `m[36][0]='X'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because you don't have line breaks in your printing loops, and this is exacerbated because you print spaces for the most part (which are, of course, invisible). If you add a `printf("\n");` after your inner printing loop (so the following code), and replace `m[37][-40]='X';` with `m[37][0]='X';`, then it should work (it did when I ran it):

```
for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
    for(j=0; j<MAX; j++)
        printf("%c", m[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I also replaced spaces with periods (`'.'`) to make it more obvious.

Comment: It's definitely the reason Jashaszum. Lu Tub's console or screen is no doubt 80 characters wide.